# C# Selenium Edge Driver unable to download file - Keep file prompt shows up

Tags: c#, selenium, automation, webdriver

I am using C# with Selenium for QA automation, and I am having issues with downloading an .xml file, because a prompt is always showing up asking if I want to keep the file. It also opens a second tab to execute the download, closing it after the prompt shows up.
[keep file prompt][1]

Using Chrome I do not see this behavior.
I searched all over and could not find a EdgeOptions() and/or AddArguments() capable of taking care of this issue.

Any ideas?

Comment: Update the question with your code trials.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use JS to interact with elements in another browser. I have had such experience and I used if else statement in my method to handle that problem. Just look trough the Selenium documentation, JS with selenium examples and so long so for.

Answer (score 0):

Just add this to your `OneTimeSetup` method. Make sure to run Visual Studio as administrator. This works since Edge 105+:

```
public void SetEdgeXmlDownloadPolicy()
    {
        var keyName = "Software\\Policies\\Microsoft\\Edge\\";
        var valueName = "ExemptFileTypeDownloadWarnings";
        var valueData = @"{""domains"": ["" * ""], ""file_extension"": ""xml""}";

        var currentUser = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.CurrentUser, RegistryView.Registry64);
        var currentKey = currentUser.OpenSubKey(keyName, true);

        if (currentKey == null)
           currentKey = currentUser.CreateSubKey(keyName);

        if (currentKey.GetValue(valueName) == null)
            currentKey.SetValue(valueName, valueData);           
    }
```